# Is Iron Man: Armored Adventures a purely stand alone series, or does this version of Tony exist in some other universe outside of 616?

Tags: marvel, cartoon, iron-man, parallel-universe, continuity

In 2009, Marvel created a CGI series. **Iron Man: Armored Adventures.*  While this was likely done to capitalize on the MCU film **Iron Man** that came out around the same time,  it took an *entirely different* track in telling Tony Stark's hero story...

- he was not yet the CEO of Stark International, but a 16 year old prodigy who had been working on a prototype of the Iron Man tech with his father, Howard Stark;
- he wasn't injured by a terrorist attack on foreign soil, but by the Sabotage of his dad's business partner, Obadiah Staine (who had a lovely daughter, Whitney who was infatuated/child hood friends with Tony)
- Though technically brilliant enough to create and advance the Iron Man armor by himself, Tony *did not* have the virtually limitless funds of Stark International at his disposal
- His best friends, James Rhodes (War Machine) and Pepper Pots (daughter of a police detective) were "let in" on his identity, which was **kept secret** from the public, more inline with the majority of comics history. Happy Hogan was there, but wasn't n the know.
- His Arc reactor more or less followed the example provided in the movie, but needed periodic recharging or changing, especially when he used it to power his armor.
- A lot of other heroes were presented as being younger kids as well (Jean Grey, Black Panther, War Machine.)
- Tony was less "humorously snarky" and more "teenage angsty". with his dad's death adding a very "Batman"-ish element of anger and vengeance to his story, especially given that Obadiah had control over his company and Tony suspected him of being complicit in his dad's death, as well as trying to steal the Iron Man armor tech.
- Enemies such as the Crimson Dynamo, the Living Laser, A.I.M., and even the Mandarin are all present, but they are all altered (The Mandarin himself is *also* a teenager in this version.)

It also has arguably one of *the* most kickass cartoon themes of the 2000s, shown with scenes of the series here:

Granted, new versions of comics are made into cartoon shows all the time, but Marvel tends to "Fold these in" to their continuity by marking them as different timelines or dimensions, i.e., it *is* factual, but it just didn't happen on earth 616.

Given that this series occurred pre Multiverse, is the **IM:AA** series just a stand alone cartoon, or, in a more meta sense, does it take place within the establish Marvel Multiverse?

If it is, is there any official Marvel data as to *which* universe this take place in?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I can't find any proof that it takes place in on [Earth-904913](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Earth-904913) although the Wiki seems pretty confident about it.

Comment: @Valorum there is a comic and novel but not sure if they’re just retellings of the series or new stories set in it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - A quick look on Amazon and Goodreads reveals a veritable crapload of kids 'reader' books, tie-in short chapter novels, mini comics, sticker books and more.

Comment: @Valorum So then it _does_ count as an "official" alternative continuity within the Marvel canon, then?

Comment: @Russhiro - I honestly don't know. It could just as easily be part of an existing continuity. in the same way that the Earth-616 stuff crosses over.

Comment: "his dad's death adding a very "Batman"-ish element of anger and vengeance to his story, especially given that Obadiah had control over his company and Tony suspected him of being complicit in his dad's death" — you may be thinking of Hamlet rather than Batman.

Answer (score 1):

This series as 2021 is a stand alone series.

The code of this continuity is Earth-904913 and this continuity don´t have anything else so unless marvel change something this is a stand alone series

Comment: If it's in a universe (you say Earth-904913) then it *is* part of the Marvel Multiverse, and *isn't* a stand-alone show by the terms of the question, no?

Comment: No, because not all universe interact the same way.

Comment: this series don´t interact with the rest of the universe like for example Ultimate Spider-man and Avengers Assemble

Comment: As Lethal Carrot has pointed out, there's a bunch of kids books, comics and other bumf also based in the same fictional universe.

Comment: Also, aside from the (dubiously sourced) wiki, can you provide any evidence that this is its own universe?

Comment: Tony Stark is a teenager, Obidiah Stane have a daughter, Cryson dynamos is Ivan Vanko and not Anton Vanko, this series have the same characters as earth-616 and similar powers but there are not the same people.